# Count and max aggregate function in same table in one query

Tags: sql

I have to do count and max aggregate function in same query. For example I have history table contains date column. I need to retrieve the latest date as well as count (*) with some criteria. Criteria is applicable for only count(*) . I am able to retrieve the latest date using max and rank function.But could not merge both. Could you please assist?

Update:

Scenario : Customer buys/sells  Shares.

Input: Table Share_history and Table Customer and Table Share and Table Share_Status

Customer   :

```
Cust_id    |Cust_name            
    1      |A        
    2      |B
```

Share   :

```
Share_id|Share_Name|Owner|  
10      |ABC       |XYZ  |  
20      |BCD       |MNC  |
```

Share_Status   :

```
Share_Status_Id|Share_Status_Name  
1              |Buy  
2              |Sell
```

Share_history :

```
Share_history _id|Share_id|Trans_date|Share_status_Id|Cust_id  
100              |10       |12/12/14 | 1             |1   
101              |10       |24/12/14 | 2             |1    
102              |10       |14/01/15 | 1             |1   
103              |10       |28/02/15 | 2             |1    
103              |10       |16/03/15 | 1             |1
```

Output: latest Trans_date and count(no of times specific share was bought(1)) and Cust_id=1.

Query:

```
select share1.Share_id,SHAREHIST.Latest_Date,SHAREHIST.buycount
from Share share1 left outer join
     (select share_id,max(Trans_date) keep(dense_rank last order by share_id) as Latest_Date,
             (select count(*) as buycount from Share_history where Share_status_id=1 and Share_id=share1.Share_id)
      from Share_history
      group by Share_id
     ) SHAREHIST 
     on SHAREHIST.share_id=share1.share_id
```

EXPECTED   :

```
Share_id|Latest_Date|buycount       
10      |16/03/15  | 3
```

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result. Also tag the dbms. And show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
SELECT 
    Share_id
    ,Trans_Date
    ,COUNT(Share_id) buycount
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM Share_history SH 
    WHERE Trans_Date = (SELECT MAX(Trans_Date) FROM Share_history)
) SH
GROUP BY Share_id, Trans_Date
```

Rest of the joins I think you can add.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
select sh.share_id, max(trans_date) as trans_date, count(*) as buy_count,
from share_history sh
where cust_id = 1
group by sh.share_id;
```